# When i try write into google search engine it written in url?

Tags: android, google-maps, browser, webview, android-edittext

I have create an android application
In that application i have one use of browser
So i have create a browser in android application
But my problem is that - when i try to write any thing in google search engine it written in url of edittext control (i have load a google page as a url) and my code is below

```
    public void onClick(View b)
 {

wv=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    WebSettings settings=wv.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    wv.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    EditText et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    String url=et.getText().toString().trim();
    wv.loadUrl("http://"+url);

}

private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient
{

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: some code will continue... maybe?

Answer (score 1):

You have to put `String url=et.getText().toString().trim();` in some `Button click` event

like below

```
ib_load.setOnClickListener(new  View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        String url=et.getText().toString().trim();
         wv.loadUrl("http://"+url);

        }
    });
```

and also make your `WebViewClient`

```
 private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
  @Override
  public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
     view.loadUrl(url);
     return true;
  }
}
```

and for more information go to this [demo link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_webview_layout.htm). I hope this help you.

Comment: hey my friends i have try this but it not work can you give other solution please thanks in advance.

Comment: i try your code but same problem occures and i have not enough point so that i can show you images